# Showing uploaded image Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

I'm uploading an image using Flask-Uploads. File uploads to the folder `img`inside the app folder. So the paths is 'app/img/'.

Flask-Uploads setup:

```
app.config['UPLOADED_IMG_DEST']='img'
photos = UploadSet('img', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)
```

Files saves successfully and return url:

```
filename = photos.save(image)
url = photos.url(filename)
```

URL: `http://example.com:5000/_uploads/img/cb6b8061-0b9f-47a6-b4b0-d2212b97a8b3.jpg`

> Image name generated randomly and picture is in the 'img' directory.

When I'm trying to access the link, or put it in `<img src"...>` it returns `404 Not Found`

**TRIED:** without `_updates` in the path

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to serve static files? `send_static_file` and `send_from_directory` can be used i guess to fix your problem.

Comment: @senaps I tried send_from_directory and it was working, but it returns the file, whereas I need a link to the file, because I'm using js to change image on the page. But thanks for comment